# Mac OS Lion - Always show menubar with fullscreen apps?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, terminal, osx-lion

Does anyone know if it is possible to keep the menubar in Mac OS Lion **visible** for fullscreen apps instead of hidden until hovered over? I imagine there's some Terminal command I can enter to adjust this preference.

Comment: See here: http://superuser.com/questions/302604/keep-menu-bar-even-in-full-screen-mode

Comment: Just turn on dock hiding and use the zoom button to maximize window size.

Comment: Moom or SizeUp would make maximizing easier. Another option is to use http://homepage.mac.com/khsu/DejaMenu/DejaMenu.html to access the menu bar in full screen applications. I haven't verified that it works in Lion though...

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19160/how-to-always-show-menubar-with-fullscreen-apps
The Desktop option is really cool.

Answer (score 1):

It would kind of defeat the purpose to call it FullScreen and then allow a way to not make it full screen. The point of full screen is to reduce the distractions, one of which would be the menu bar.

All of the other regular Mac sites are reporting the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than making the app in question full-screen, you might try moving it to a different desktop instead. The menu bar will still be there, and that app is the only one that has to be on that desktop, therefore creating the effect it seems you want to get.